# Why the email address never receive the test?

Tags: php, ajax, bash, email, centos

I am working on a script that sends a test to a specific email address from an ip address, the email and the ip are both passed as parameters throught php file.

Here is the php code:

```php
foreach ($id as $option) { 
                    //echo $option."\r\n";
                    $option = explode("-",$option);
                    $option = $option[1];
                    shell_exec("sudo /root/testip.sh $option $email");
                echo "\n". "This IPs Selected ".$option;
      }
```

This is testip.sh file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

#  variables de réglages

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$1 PROJ=$2  'bash -s' <<EOF
yum install -y mailx

mailx -r "Some from here <no-reply@example.com>" -s "Important - $1" $2 <<END

How are good
Bye
END

exit
EOF

exit
```

The problem is i don't get any result in my inbox or spam folders.
I think the problem is i some missing service in my vps but im not sure about that!

Comment: your server is set up to send emails?

Comment: Yes mail port is opened and i already installed ``mailx`` and ``sendmail`` services

Comment: What are the symptoms of the problem you are having? Also, why does the `testip.sh` script attempt to install `mailx` if your host is already set up to send mail? Finally why call the script `testip.sh`, when it is not testing any IP addresses.  Please update the question to make clear; 1) What you want to happen, 2) What is actually happening.

Comment: The question is updated

Comment: You should attempt to debug this problem one step at a time.  First, run mailx with a simple message on the remote host to see if that works. Then run mailx with the heredoc copied from your `testip.sh` script. The run the script on its own. Then run the script from within php.  At each stage, if the message does notcome through, then you have a better idea of where the problem is.